# How can I add the extra elements in the available CIF file for refinement?

Tags: vesta, x-ray-diffraction, fullprof-suite

I have prepared Lithium ferrite samples doped with Zinc, Titanium, and Manganese. After taking the XRD data I wanted to perform Rietveld refinement. But the problem is that I have cif data available only for Zinc substituted Lithium ferrite. Although I have gone about refinement and it works somewhat, how can I insert the missing substituent in the cif file? Please help.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add to it relevant part of your existing CIF file? I think only the _atom_site table is relevant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My recommendation is to look for another system with similar characteristics and adapt the CIF to your case.